# UIWebVIew in iOS 12.2 not showing HTML camera

Tags: ios, html, cordova, ionic-framework, uiwebview

I have an old app using Sencha Architect and Cordova
The issue arises in the latest iOS update 12.2. I used to pop up the camera in the code by doing this.
this is the code reduced for the purpose of this question.

```
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  input.click();
```

The thing is that if I create an ionic project, that code works very well. (ionic doesn't use uiwebview)
In my project which is very old that code stopped working since the last update but it runs if I place it in a simulator, however it only allows me to select pictures from the gallery.

The things I tried are 
Updating to the last version of Cordova
Updating the Cordova iOS project to version 5

But still no luck.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is the actual problem? Is the camera not displaying?

Comment: yes, the camera is not displaying